# edit text value pass wrong to the server in Hebrew langaue

Tags: php, android

I am trying to pass a strret address from my application to my PHP server.
when i print the address in the Log.d i got:

```
העמק 57 גבעת אלה
```

but the server response is:

```
$place = $_POST["address"];
$output["addressEditText"] = $place;
```

and this is what i got from the server:

```
???? 57 ???? ???
```

i need that the server will support also hebrew alphabet.
just for notice this response is not from the DB i just copy and past the value of the parameter into the output response.

this is my page code:

```
   <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 9/17/2015
 * Time: 2:56 PM
 */
include 'response_process.php';
include 'gcm.php';
require_once 'DBFunctions.php';


class CreateEvent implements ResponseProcess {
    public function dataProcess($dblink)
    {
        $output = array();
        $dbF = new DBFunctions($dblink);
        $sport = $_POST["sport_type"];
        $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$_POST["date"])));
        $s_time =$date." ".$_POST["s_time"];
        $e_time = $date." ".$_POST["e_time"];
        $s_time =date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($s_time));
        $e_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($e_time));
        $lon = $_POST["lon"];
        $lat = $_POST["lat"];
        $event_type = $_POST["event_type"];
        $max_p = $_POST["max_participants"];
        $sched = $_POST["scheduled"];
        $gen = $_POST["gender"];
        $min_age = $_POST["minAge"];
        $manager = $_POST["manager"];
        $mng_name = $_POST["manager_name"];
        $place = $_POST["address"];
        $output["addressEditText"] = $place;
        $mode = $_POST["mode"];
        if($sched == "true"){
            $exp_val = "";
            $type = "";
            $repeat = $_POST["repeat"];
            $duration = $_POST["duration"];
            $expiration_tag = $_POST["sched_tag"];

            switch($expiration_tag){
                case "unlimited":{
                    $exp_val = "unlimited";
                    $type = $exp_val;
                    break;
                }
                case "Year":{
                    $exp_val = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST["value"]));
                    $type = "date";
                    break;
                }
                case "events_number":
                    $exp_val = $_POST["value"];
                    $type = "counter";
                    break;
                case "by_date":
                    $exp_val = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST["value"]));
                    $type = "date";
                    break;
            }
            $output["repeat"] = $repeat;
            $output["duration"] = $duration;
            $output["exp_val"] = $exp_val;
            $output["type"] = $type;
        }

        if($mode == "edit"){
            $event_id = $_POST["event_id"];
            $invited_users_size = 0;
            if(isset($_POST["invitedUsers"])){
                $participants = $_POST["invitedUsers"];
                $json_uesr_ids = json_decode($participants);
                $invited_users_size = count($json_uesr_ids);
            }

            if(isset($_POST["invitedUsers"])){
                $result_q = $dbF -> DeleteEventFromAttending($event_id);
                if(!$result_q)
                {
                    $output["flag"]= "delete failed";
                    $output["msg"] = $result_q;
                    return json_encode($output);
                }else {
                    $participants = $_POST["invitedUsers"];
                    $json_uesr_ids = json_decode($participants);
                    $output["json_users"] = $json_uesr_ids;
                    $get_users_reg_ids = $dbF->getUserSByIds($json_uesr_ids, count($json_uesr_ids));
                    $reg_ids = array();
                    $i = 0;
                    while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_users_reg_ids)) {
                        $reg_ids[$i] = $row_user["gcm_id"];
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $output["ids"] = $reg_ids;
                    $output["size"] = count($json_uesr_ids);


                    $result_q = $dbF->InsertIntoAttendingUpdatedUsers($json_uesr_ids, $event_id, count($json_uesr_ids),"awaiting reply");
                    $output["insert_res"] = $result_q;
                    if (!$result_q) {
                        $output["flag"] = "update_insert failed";
                        $output["msg"] = $result_q;
                        return json_encode($output);
                    } else {
                        $output["flag"] = "update_success";
                        $output["msg"] = $result_q;
                    }
                    //send notification on update to users
                    $gcm = new GCM();
                    $data = array();
                    $message = "The event " . $sport . " in " . $place . " in " . $date . " updated,Please click on Join in order to confirm registration.";
                    $data['message'] = $message;
                    $data['date'] = $date;
                    $data['private'] = $event_type;
                    $data['start_time'] = date("H:i", strtotime($s_time));
                    $data['end_time'] = date("H:i", strtotime($e_time));
                    $data['inviter'] = $mng_name;
                    $data['event_id'] = $event_id;
                    $data['location'] = $place;
                    $gcm_res = $gcm->send_notification($reg_ids, $data);
                    $output["gcm_res"] = $gcm_res;
                    //send notification on update to users
                }
            }
            $result_q = $dbF ->checkIfEventIsExistBeforeUpdate($lon,$lat,$date,$s_time,$e_time,$event_id);
            if(!$result_q)
            {
                $output["flag"]= "select failed";
                $output["msg"] = $result_q;
                return json_encode($output);
            }
            else {
                $no_of_rows_check_event = mysqli_num_rows($result_q);
                if ($no_of_rows_check_event > 0) {
                    $output["flag"] = "failed";
                    $output["msg"] = "Place is already occupied in this time";
                }else{
                    $result_q = $dbF -> UpdateEvent($event_id,$sport,$s_time,$e_time,$place,$lon,$lat,$event_type,$gen,$min_age,$max_p,'1',$invited_users_size,$sched,$output["repeat"],$output["duration"],$output["type"],$output["exp_val"]);
                    $output["res"] = $result_q;
                    $output["sched"] = $sched;

                    if($sched == "true")
                    {
                        $output["sched_res"] = "true";
                    }
                    else{
                        $output["sched_res"] = "false";
                    }
                    $affected_row = mysqli_affected_rows($dblink);
                    if(!$result_q)
                    {
                        $output["flag"]= "update_failed";
                        $output["query_res"] = $result_q;
                        $output["msg"] = "failed to update event";
                        $output["affected row"] = $affected_row;
                    }
                    else{
                        $output["flag"]= "update_success";
                        $output["query_res"] = $result_q;
                        $output["msg"] = "success to update event";
                        $output["affected row"] = $affected_row;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else{

            $result_q = $dbF ->checkIfEventIsExist($lon,$lat,$date,$s_time,$e_time);
            $output["query"] = $result_q;
            if(!$result_q)
            {
                $output["flag"]= "select failed";
                $output["msg"] = $result_q;
                return json_encode($output);
            }
            else{
                $no_of_rows_check_event = mysqli_num_rows($result_q);
                $output["no_of_rows"] = $no_of_rows_check_event;
                if($no_of_rows_check_event > 0)
                {
                    $output["flag"] = "failed";
                    $output["msg"] = "Place is already occupied in this time";
                }else{
                    $output["flag"] = "success";
                    $output["msg"] = "insert event";
                    $num_of_invited_users = 0;
                    if(isset($_POST["jsoninvited"])){
                        $json = $_POST["jsoninvited"];
                        $json = json_decode($json);
                        $num_of_invited_users = (count($json));
                        $output["size_invited"] = count($json);
                    }

                    $result = $dbF -> InsertNewEvent($manager,$sport,$s_time,$e_time,$place,$lon,$lat,$event_type,$gen,$min_age,$max_p,$num_of_invited_users,$sched,$output["repeat"],$output["duration"],$output["type"],$output["exp_val"]);
                    if (!$result) {
                        $output["flag"] = "failed to create event";
                        // return (json_encode($output));

                    }
                    else{

                        if(isset($_POST["jsoninvited"])){

                            $event_s_res = $dbF ->getEventIdByDateAndTime($date,$s_time,$e_time);
                            $output["my_squery"] =$event_s_res;

                            if(!$event_s_res)
                            {
                                $output["flag"] = "failed";
                                $output["msg"] = "Event id not found";
                            }
                            else{
                                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($event_s_res);
                                $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($event_s_res);
                                if($no_of_rows > 1 || $no_of_rows == 0)
                                {
                                    $output["flag"] = "failed";
                                    $output["msg"] = "Event id not found";
                                }
                                else{
                                    $event_id = $row["event_id"];
                                    $json = $_POST["jsoninvited"];
                                    $json = json_decode($json);
                                    $output["size_invited"] = count($json);
                                    $size_of_param = (count($json));
                                    $event_user_s_res = $dbF -> getUserIdAndRegId($json,$size_of_param);

                                    if(!$event_user_s_res)
                                    {
                                        $output["flag"] = "failed";
                                        $output["msg"] = "user id not found";
                                    }

                                    $result = $dbF->insertIntoAttendingTable($event_user_s_res, $event_id, $size_of_param);
                                    $insert_query_res = $result["res"];
                                    $output["query"] = $result["query"];
                                    $registration_ids = $result["reg_ids"];

                                    if(!$insert_query_res)
                                    {
                                        $output["flag"] = "failed";
                                        $output["msg"] = "failed to insert to attending table";
                                    }
                                    else{

                                        $output["registred_ids"] = $registration_ids;
                                        $output["msg"] = "success to insert into attending";
                                        $gcm = new GCM();
                                        $data = array();
                                        $message = "Would like to invite you to play ".$sport.", Please click on Join in order to add you into the event.";
                                        $data['message'] = $message;
                                        $data['date'] = $date;
                                        $data['start_time'] = date("H:i",strtotime($s_time));
                                        $data['end_time'] = date("H:i",strtotime($e_time));
                                        $data['inviter'] = $mng_name;
                                        $data['private'] = $event_type;
                                        $data['event_id'] = $event_id;
                                        $data['location'] = $place;
                                        $output["gcm_message"]=$data;
                                        $gcm_res = $gcm->send_notification($registration_ids,$data);
                                        $output["gcm_res"] = $gcm_res;

                                    } //els of $insert_query_res
                                } //else of  $no_of_rows > 1 || $no_of_rows == 0


                            } // else  of $event_s_res
                        } //if isset($_POST["invitedUsers"]

                    } // if $result
                }
            }
        }//get inside creating event mode.
        return json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

this is my client side:

```
 public void sendDataToDBController() {
    BasicNameValuePair mode_req;
    LatLng lonlat = locationTool.getLocationFromAddress(addressEditText.getText().toString());
    if(lonlat == null)
    {
        Log.d("location is:","location not found");
        sv.scrollTo(0, 0);
        addressEditText.setError("Location was not found!");
        return;
    }
    Log.d("found location",lonlat.latitude+""+lonlat.longitude);
    BasicNameValuePair tagreq = new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.TAG_REQUEST,"create_event");
    Log.d("event mode",mode);

    if(mode.equals(Constants.MODE_CREATE))
    {
        Log.d("event mode","create");
         mode_req = new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.TAG_MODE,Constants.MODE_CREATE);
    }
    else {
        Log.d("event mode","update");
         mode_req = new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.TAG_MODE, Constants.MODE_UPDATE);
    }

    Log.d("addressEditText",addressEditText.getText().toString());
    BasicNameValuePair address = new BasicNameValuePair("address",addressEditText.getText().toString());
    BasicNameValuePair sport = new BasicNameValuePair("sport_type",sportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    Log.d("sport_type",sportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    BasicNameValuePair date = new BasicNameValuePair("date",btnStartdate.getText().toString());
    BasicNameValuePair startTime = new BasicNameValuePair("s_time",btnstartTime.getText().toString());
    BasicNameValuePair endTime = new BasicNameValuePair("e_time",btnendTime.getText().toString());
    BasicNameValuePair longtitude = new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.TAG_LONG,String.valueOf(lonlat.longitude));
    BasicNameValuePair latitude = new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.TAG_LAT,String.valueOf(lonlat.latitude));
    BasicNameValuePair event_type = new BasicNameValuePair("event_type",String.valueOf(privateEventCbox.isChecked()));
    BasicNameValuePair gender = new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.TAG_GEN,String.valueOf(genderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    BasicNameValuePair min_age = new BasicNameValuePair("minAge",String.valueOf(minAgeEditText.getText()));
    BasicNameValuePair participants = new BasicNameValuePair("max_participants",maxParticipantsEdittext.getText().toString());
    BasicNameValuePair scheduled = new BasicNameValuePair("scheduled",String.valueOf(reccuringEventCbox.isChecked()));
    BasicNameValuePair mob_manager = new BasicNameValuePair("manager",sm.getUserDetails().get(Constants.TAG_USERID));
    BasicNameValuePair manager_name = new BasicNameValuePair("manager_name",sm.getUserDetails().get(Constants.TAG_NAME));


    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    if(mode.equals(Constants.MODE_UPDATE)){
        BasicNameValuePair eventId = new BasicNameValuePair("event_id",event_id);
        nameValuePairList.add(eventId);
    }

    if(invitedUsers != null)
    {
        if(invitedUsers.size() > 0)
        {

            String[] users = new String[invitedUsers.size()];
            JSONArray invited = new JSONArray();

            for(int i=0 ; i < invitedUsers.size(); i++)
            {
                if(mode.equals(Constants.MODE_CREATE))
                    users[i]= invitedUsers.get(i).getMobile();
                else
                    users[i]= invitedUsers.get(i).getId();
                invited.put(users[i]);
            }
            String json = invited.toString();
            Log.d("string array", Arrays.toString(users));
            BasicNameValuePair invitedusers = new BasicNameValuePair("invitedUsers",Arrays.toString(users));
            BasicNameValuePair jsonInvited = new BasicNameValuePair("jsoninvited",json);
            nameValuePairList.add(invitedusers);
            nameValuePairList.add(jsonInvited);
        }
    }
    if(sched_res != null && reccuringEventCbox.isChecked() == true){

        String repeatval ="";
        String duration ="";
        String tag = "";
        String val = "";
        BasicNameValuePair sched_val = null;
        try {
             repeatval = sched_res.getString("repeat");
             duration = sched_res.getString("duration");
            JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(sched_res.getString("radio_group"));
            tag = jsonarr.getJSONObject(0).getString(Constants.TAG_REQUEST);
            sched_val = new BasicNameValuePair("value",jsonarr.getJSONObject(0).getString("val"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BasicNameValuePair sched_repeat = new BasicNameValuePair("repeat",repeatval);
        BasicNameValuePair sched_duration = new BasicNameValuePair("duration",duration);
        BasicNameValuePair sched_tag = new BasicNameValuePair("sched_tag",tag);
        nameValuePairList.add(sched_repeat);
        nameValuePairList.add(sched_duration);
        nameValuePairList.add(sched_tag);
        if(sched_val != null)
            nameValuePairList.add(sched_val);

    }

    nameValuePairList.add(manager_name);
    nameValuePairList.add(mob_manager);
    nameValuePairList.add(tagreq);
    nameValuePairList.add(mode_req);
    nameValuePairList.add(sport);
    nameValuePairList.add(date);
    nameValuePairList.add(address);
    nameValuePairList.add(startTime);
    nameValuePairList.add(endTime);
    nameValuePairList.add(min_age);
    nameValuePairList.add(longtitude);
    nameValuePairList.add(latitude);
    nameValuePairList.add(event_type);
    nameValuePairList.add(participants);
    nameValuePairList.add(scheduled);
    nameValuePairList.add(gender);
    dbController = new DBcontroller(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),this);
    dbController.execute(nameValuePairList);
}
```

Comment: Are you using  ´<meta charset=utf-8" />´ in your page?

Comment: please share code through which you upload data to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching for a while i solved this issue by:
add this code in my server side:

```
 if(!mysqli_set_charset($dblink, 'utf8')) {
    echo 'the connection is not in utf8';
    exit();
}
```